# Where does this Gamma formula come from?

Tags: luminosity

This is the derivation of formula of Gamma Correction for CRT monitors.

I am not finding this in any book or web-site. Books seem to derive this formula in different ways.

Can anyone please tell me the explanation of this derivation?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction

Comment: @mmesser314, yes, I saw. But, formula seems to be different.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Note that this site has [MathJax enabled](//physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation), which means you can use Latex-like syntax to add in equations for readability.

Comment: Kyle is right: your question would be much easier to understand and respond to if it were more than just some snapshots. Writing out the equations would take a little time, but you would be much more likely to get good answers.